# Date data not displaying in tableview

Tags: javafx

hello everyone the `Date` value does not showing in the tableview, i pass the correct parameters but i think i need to format the Date data to transform that data to a  `string` value, i am using the `Object Property` for the `Date` and the `SimpleStringProperty` and `SimpleIntergerProperty` for the `name, lastname, and  ID`

in the Insert Method i used `preparedstatement` to save the data in the Database, that seems ok, i declare in the database `fecha_nacimiento` as `Date`, but when i am showing the date data into the `tableview`, like i said before the tablecolumn appears empy

i put all my code here to revision or improvement of that error, i need some help to review the process in `setting or formating` the value of the table column date to string.

any help could be helpful. regards.

date data empy in tableview:[image]

modifications 1 in the controller @Daniel Subelman:[image]

modifications 2 class persona @Daniel Subelman:[image]

issue after modifications @Daniel Subelman:[image]

constructor exception error 1:[image]

unsopported operation error:[image]

nulpointer exception error:[image]

here is my `controller` code

```
   package application;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;





public class ConexionController implements Initializable {



        @FXML TableView<Persona>  tablacliente;
        @FXML TableColumn<Persona, String> nombrescol;
        @FXML TableColumn<Persona,String > apellidoscol;
        @FXML TableColumn<Persona, Integer>  clienteid;
        @FXML TableColumn<Persona,LocalDate>  fechacli;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        Connection Conexion=null;
        @FXML private Button btn;
        @FXML private Button mtn;
        @FXML private Button lmp;
        @FXML private Button mts;
        @FXML private Button bqd;
        @FXML private Button bqape;
        @FXML private TextField nm;
        @FXML private TextField ap;
        @FXML private TextField bq;
        @FXML private TextField bqa;
        @FXML private MenuBar menucombo;
        @FXML private Button botonborrar;
        @FXML private TextField borrar;
        @FXML private DatePicker mifecha;

        @Override


        public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
            clienteid.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory <Persona, Integer>("id_cliente"));
            nombrescol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory <Persona, String>("nombres"));
             apellidoscol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory <Persona, String>("apellidos"));
            //fechacli.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory <Persona, LocalDate>("fechacliente"));//

             DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

             fechacli.setCellFactory(column -> {
                 return new TableCell<Persona, LocalDate>() {
                     @Override
                     protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                         super.updateItem(item, empty);

                         if (item == null || empty) {
                             setText(null);
                         } else {
                             setText(formatter.format(item));

                         }
                     }
                 };
             });

             seleccionaregistros();
             seleccionanombre();
             seleccionapellido(); 
        }



        public void borraregistro() {
             int id = Integer.parseInt(borrar.getText());
             String consulta=" delete  from cliente where id=? ";

             Connection conn=null;{

                  try {

                      conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "milkas87");
                      PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement(consulta);
                      ps.setInt(1, id);
                      ps.executeQuery();


                  }catch (SQLException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                  alert.setTitle("Informacion");
                  alert.setHeaderText(null);
                  alert.setContentText("Registro borrado correctamente");
                  alert.showAndWait();      
             }
             seleccionaregistros();
        } 


    public void conexion(){

        try {
            Conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "milkas87");

            } 

        catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         if(Conexion!=null) {
             Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
             alert.setTitle("Informacion");
             alert.setHeaderText(null);
             alert.setContentText("Conexion Exitosa");
             alert.showAndWait();

         }

    }

    public void insertaregistro() {

          Connection conn=null;
             try {

                 conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "milkas87");
                 Statement insertar=conn.createStatement();
                 insertar.executeUpdate("insert into cliente (nombre, apellido,fecha_nacimiento) values ('"+nm.getText()+"', '"+ap.getText()+"', '"+((TextField)mifecha.getEditor()).getText()+"')");

                 if(conn!=null) {
                     Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                     alert.setTitle("Informacion");
                     alert.setHeaderText(null);
                     alert.setContentText("Registro Insertado correctamente");
                     alert.showAndWait();
                 }

             } catch (SQLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             seleccionaregistros();

    }


    public void seleccionaregistros() {
        ObservableList <Persona> data =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
          Connection conn=null;{
              try {

                 conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "milkas87");
                  Statement mostrar=conn.createStatement();
                  ResultSet rs;
                  rs= mostrar.executeQuery("select * from cliente");


                  while ( rs.next() ) 
                  {
                     data.add(new Persona(

                             rs.getString("nombre"),
                             rs.getString("apellido"),
                             rs.getInt("id"),
                             rs.getDate(4).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate())
                             );
                     tablacliente.setItems(data);
                  }

              } catch (SQLException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

         }

    }

    public void seleccionanombre() {
         String nombre = bq.getText();
        ObservableList <Persona> busqueda =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
         String consulta=" select * from cliente where nombre like ? " ;

         Connection conn=null;{

              try {

                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "milkas87");
                  PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement(consulta);
                  ps.setString(1, nombre);
                  ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();

                 while ( rs.next() ) 
                  {
                     busqueda.add(new Persona(

                             rs.getString("nombre"),
                             rs.getString("apellido"),
                             rs.getInt("id"),
                             rs.getDate(4).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate())
                             );

                  }

              } catch (SQLException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

              tablacliente.setItems(busqueda); 
         }

    }

    public void seleccionapellido() {
         String apellido = bqa.getText();
        ObservableList <Persona> busquedape =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
         String consulta=" select * from cliente where apellido like ? " ;

         Connection conn=null;{

              try {

                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "milkas87");
                  PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement(consulta);
                  ps.setString(1, apellido);
                  ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();

                 while ( rs.next() ) 
                  {
                     busquedape.add(new Persona(

                             rs.getString("nombre"),
                             rs.getString("apellido"),
                             rs.getInt("id"),
                             rs.getDate(4).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate())
                             );

                  }

              } catch (SQLException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

              tablacliente.setItems(busquedape); 
         }

    }

    public void inicializacombo() {
         try {
                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
                fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("VistaCombo.fxml"));
                Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setTitle("Datos Del Cliente");
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
    }

    public void limpiatexto() {
        nm.clear();
        ap.clear();
        bq.clear();
        bqa.clear();
        borrar.clear();
    }


    public void cargarconexion() {
     btn.setOnAction(e->{
            conexion();
        });
    }

    public void cargarregistro() {
         mtn.setOnAction(e->{
                insertaregistro();
            });
        }
    public void borrarcasillatexto() {
         lmp.setOnAction(e->{
                limpiatexto();
            });
        }

    public void mostrartodo() {
        mts.setOnAction(e->{
            seleccionaregistros();
        });
    }

    public void buscanm() {
         bqd.setOnAction(e->{
          seleccionanombre();

            });
    }

    public void buscaape() {
        bqape.setOnAction(e->{
        seleccionapellido();

      });
    }

    public void borraregistroid() {
        botonborrar.setOnAction(e->{
            borraregistro();

      });
    }

}
```

here is my `Persona Class` Code

```
 package application;


import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Persona {



    private StringProperty nombres;
    private StringProperty apellidos;
    private IntegerProperty id_cliente;
    private ObjectProperty <LocalDate>fechacliente;

    public Persona (String nombres, String apellidos, Integer id_cliente, LocalDate fechacliente) {
        this.nombres=  new SimpleStringProperty (nombres);
        this.apellidos= new SimpleStringProperty ( apellidos);
        this.id_cliente=new SimpleIntegerProperty (id_cliente);
        this.fechacliente= new SimpleObjectProperty<>(fechacliente);
    }


public LocalDate getFechaCliente() {
        return fechacliente.get();
}
public void setFechaCliente(LocalDate fechacliente) {
        this.fechacliente = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(fechacliente);
}
public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> fechaClienteProperty() {
        return fechacliente;
}

public String getNombres() {
    return nombres.get();
}

public  void  setNombres(String nombres) {
    this.nombres=new SimpleStringProperty (nombres);
}


public String getApellidos() {
    return apellidos.get();
}

public  void  setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    this.apellidos=new SimpleStringProperty ( apellidos);
}


public Integer getId_cliente() {
    return id_cliente.get();
}

public  void  setid_cliente(Integer id_cliente) {
    this.id_cliente=new SimpleIntegerProperty (id_cliente);
}

}
```

here is my `FXML` code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="497.0" prefWidth="943.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ConexionController">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutY="-3.0" prefHeight="605.0" prefWidth="1084.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="145.0" layoutY="109.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cargarconexion" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="117.0" text="Prueba Conexion" />
            <Button fx:id="mtn" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="183.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cargarregistro" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="117.0" text="Inserta Registro" />
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="279.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="105.0" text="NOMBRES" />
            <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="327.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="79.0" text="APELLIDOS" />
            <TextField fx:id="nm" layoutX="159.0" layoutY="275.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="ap" layoutX="159.0" layoutY="323.0" />
            <Button fx:id="lmp" layoutX="159.0" layoutY="484.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#borrarcasillatexto" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Limpiar Texto" />
            <TableView fx:id="tablacliente" layoutX="355.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="383.0" prefWidth="696.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="clienteid" prefWidth="159.0" text="ID" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="nombrescol" prefWidth="159.0" text="NOMBRES" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="apellidoscol" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="169.0" text="APELLIDOS" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="fechacli" prefWidth="235.0" text="FECHA DE NACIMIENTO" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
            <Button fx:id="mts" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="109.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mostrartodo" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="117.0" text="Mostrar" />
            <TextField fx:id="bq" layoutX="554.0" layoutY="417.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
            <Button fx:id="bqd" layoutX="758.0" layoutY="417.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buscanm" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="155.0" text="BUSCAR NOMBRE" />
            <Button fx:id="bqape" layoutX="758.0" layoutY="458.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buscaape" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="155.0" text="BUSCAR POR APELLIDO" />
            <TextField fx:id="bqa" layoutX="554.0" layoutY="458.0" />
            <ComboBox layoutX="159.0" layoutY="430.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="434.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="55.0" text="GENERO" />
            <MenuBar fx:id="menucombo" layoutY="3.0">
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Agregar">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#inicializacombo" text="Datos Cliente" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
            <Button fx:id="botonborrar" layoutX="758.0" layoutY="507.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#borraregistroid" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="155.0" text="BORRAR REGISTRO" />
            <TextField fx:id="borrar" layoutX="554.0" layoutY="507.0" />
            <DatePicker fx:id="mifecha" layoutX="158.0" layoutY="371.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="375.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="FECHA DE NACIMIENTO" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

this is the error in the console

```
 javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/ROA%20PC/eclipse-workspace/Conexion/bin/application/Vista.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.sql.Date.toInstant(Unknown Source)
    at application.ConexionController.seleccionaregistros(ConexionController.java:190)
    at application.ConexionController.initialize(ConexionController.java:92)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:336)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:235)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to adapt your code to make it work without connecting to the DB. This changes will make it work.

1. In your `Persona` class:

   - Change your constructor to:

     ```
     public Persona (String nombres, String apellidos, Integer id_cliente, LocalDate fechacliente) {
         this.nombres=  new SimpleStringProperty (nombres);
         this.apellidos= new SimpleStringProperty ( apellidos);
         this.id_cliente=new SimpleIntegerProperty (id_cliente);
         this.fechacliente= new SimpleObjectProperty<>(fechacliente);
     }
     ```
   - Change the getter and setter for `fechacliente`:

     ```
     public LocalDate getFechaCliente() {
         return fechacliente.get();
     }
     public void setFechaCliente(LocalDate fechacliente) {
         this.fechacliente = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(fechacliente);
     }
     ```
   - Add `fechaClienteProperty`:

     ```
     public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> fechaClienteProperty() {
         return fechacliente;
     }
     ```
2. In your `ConexionController` change the `CellValueFactory` and `CellFactory` to:

   ```
       fechacli.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().fechaClienteProperty());

       DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMyyyy");

       fechacli.setCellFactory(column -> {
           return new TableCell<Persona, LocalDate>() {
               @Override
               protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                   super.updateItem(item, empty);

                   if (item == null || empty) {
                       setText(null);
                   } else {
                       setText(formatter.format(item));

                   }
               }
           };
       });
   ```

With this corrections it works. Hope this helps.

Comment: i have an error , i am updating the post, please see the post and comment.

Comment: Nothing yet @Daniel Subelman

Comment: i have a second issue @Daniel Subelman i post an image for the error

Comment: Your second issue is because `getDate(int i)` method from a `ResultSet` returns a `Date` (not a `LocalDate`).  To solve that issue change all `rs.getDate(4)` for `rs.getDate(4).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()`

Comment: I follow your instructions @Daniel Subelman but , i have another error, constructor exception. I posted.

Comment: i update all the post with the code modifications, i don't know what is happening, can i post the link in google drive with the java project?

Comment: @JhonMark _can i post the link with the java project_ definitely no - instead, go into a debugging session ;) strip it down even further: 1. no database, just plain hard-coded data 2. remove all unrelated properties from your data item (keep just the one the throws up 3. remove all unrelated controls the ui 4. quadruple check your spelling if you insist on using PropertyValueFactory (better not, expose and use the properties of your data item) ... you get the gist, right - get rid of the noise so you can hear the music :)

Comment: @JhonMark changes proposed solve several issues in your code (see screenshot: https://imgur.com/8iOSdX8). If you have other issues, you should first accept this answer, and either open a new question or, as mentioned above, go into a debugging session.

Comment: @Daniel Subelman please review my code, i do everything and nothing happens, the tablecolumn "fecha nacimiento" still empy.please help

Comment: this is my github link of the project https://github.com/rikardoroa/ProjectXcorpio

Comment: you are the man daniel Subelman. thanks!!